# Is it possible to call client side code from cloud (and not with push notification or live query)

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I'm using Flutter developing for mobile. I'm using Parse (Back4App) for my back end.

I do not want either of the following:

1. push notifications to solve this
2. Parse live query to solve this

(I'm aware both of the above do solve this, I have need for a different configuration)

Simple question: can I somehow trigger client-side code from cloud code if app is open? If so how?

Comment: Sockets can also be used to do similar work...you can have a look

Comment: Can you give me a little more to go off of? What to do with sockets? Sockets is pretty vague.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets this link may help you....i have done web-socket in native android but not in flutter yet so I dont have much to help you.

Comment: Looks like a very good option, similar to live queries. I'll take more options from anyone else if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with another option Back4app has to offer.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#config

For flutter, you can use the REST API version of this

https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#config

Comment: I think the REST API is way over my head but I may look into using it. Thanks for the input.